# TSQL function - Memoization (almost like at Python)

Tags: sql-server, caching, database-performance

I have a TSQL function that is quite time and resource consuming. What is important for the same parameters function always will return the same values. Of course, I can modify that function that way that there will be results caching and calculation will be made only when there is no data already calculated at the cache. Still, I thining if there is no something like memoization (for example) at Python.  At Python, we can add memoization without any modification of function. Probably implementing something like that at TSQL will be not easy or maybe not possible.  Still, maybe there is a way that simplifies such an approach that function results are cached and when the function is requested with the same parameters we get results from cache, not based calculations.

Comment: Well let's see what the function is, perhaps there is improvements we can make. We can't help you without that

Comment: @charlieface I know that one solution is to make function optimization and for that source code of that function is needed. But I'm looking for something more generic. I like the solution that is used in python. Before function, you put @cache.memoize(timeout=180) and you know that if the function was calculated at the last 180s your next request with the same parameters will be not recalculated only you get data from the cache. You don't need to make any change to function code and that sometimes is very useful.

Comment: In SQL, better performance is very specific to exactly what you are doing. For better help here, you need to supply at the least your code and table and index definitions, preferably also execution plans (via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan)